# Build Pipelines in TFS

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, jenkins

In 2009, there was a [SO question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160130/how-can-i-implement-a-build-pipeline-with-tfs).

I'm wondering if later versions of Team Foundation Server are better at longer build pipelines.  Refer features of Jenkins, TeamCity, ThoughtWorks' Go (my employer).

The visualizations of the build pipelines are important to me, as well as the notification about individual stages passing or failing.  That and the eminent clone-ability of say a 'trunk' pipeline into one for a release branch as that branch leaps into being.

Secondly, a personal holy-grail is the CI server storing its config in the SCM that's holding the buildable thing itself, and even picking up on the creation of branches silently to provision new pipelines; Can TFS be configured to store the CI definitions/scripts in its SCM side rather than its accompanying SqlServer?

Answer (score 3):

TFS build consists of three components:

1. The build definition - stored on the SQL server data tier.
2. The build workflow - a XAML file stored in the source control.
3. The supporting MSBuild scripts - usually contains user defined actions, also stored in the source control.

As the build progresses, you can see visualization of the build steps and you also get a different log for the main build and the MSBuild output.

The build definition in TFS is merely a collection of build settings, similar to CC.Net's config file and TeamCity's build configuration tab which both stored on the file system as well. Assuming there's a backup plan on the database you don't really need to store the build defintions on the source control, but if you must it's possible by exporting the `tbl_BuildDefinition` table.

The [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) adds cloning functionality for build definitions.

There's no OOTB support for provisioning build definitions from a new branch though it's fairly feasible using the TFS-API.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but just don't bother with TFS if you want advanced build pipeline automation. It simply doesn't cut it.

I have used Jenkins and TFS both extensively. Tfs is just. pure. crap. Here's why.

No down/up stream build.
No piepline/orchestraion build. (like jenkins)
Obscure ways of adding build steps and falls back to using MsBuild.
Slow and still polls the source control.
Ties you to MsTest.

And please don't point me to "Oh look you can do everything if you write a custom activity". I'm not wasting time doing development for a closed source, sub-par platform. If I am going to contribute something, it's to a FREE. OPEN SOURCE platform.

Comment: Most of your comments are incorrect and are the result of a poor understanding of the capacities of the product. Which I agree should be more discoverable. TFS uses Windows Workflow (fo good or bad0 as its orchestration engine and you can get it to do anything that you want in any order. Most capabilities are out of the box and you can customise with PowerShell and custom activities. You are also NOT tied to MS build as it supports any test platform.

Comment: @MrHinsh YOU get your understanding straight. Tell me how to build a pipeline in TFS where you fingerprint the artifact and stash it alongside the build number. Then arm or disable the next stage of build job as a downstream, and then ready a single button for deployment.

Comment: @MrHinsh There's no upstream/downstream build in TFS without getting the whole bloody TFS/Sharepoin/Workflow foundation custom step thing involved. And that is a complete utter waste of time. And even when you do, it's flaky as hell.

Comment: @MrHinsh Lol, looking at your history, you are like a TFS sales rep. Good job. Have you even seen multi-stage build process in Jenkins/Hudson/Bamboo? Actually have you even used anything other than TFS before?

Comment: :) Not a TFS Sales rep but I work with the product a lot. And yes, I have worked with Jenkins and Hudson either to migrate teams to TFS or to implement Java builds integrated with TFS when I need to build on a linux box. What you are talking about is not 'build pipeline' but a release pipeline (you don't want to rebuild for every stage in the pipleine.) This is available as part of InRelease (MSFT just bought them) and I have implemented it many times with Octopus Deploy. So while not out-of-the-box it is easy and cheap to implemnent on top of TFS 2012: http://bit.ly/18V2JSv

Comment: @MrHinsh Ok, I have to apologise for being so harsh. Crap day at work. I'll have a look into InRelease. Much appreciate it.